# Use variable inside the FOR loop

Tags: javascript

All i want to do is to call the FOR variable inside my loop. But for some reason is not working...

HTML

```
<span id="1"></span>
<span id="2"></span>
<span id="3"></span>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  var product = j;
  document.getElementById(product).innerHTML = "blah";
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cq47eo1c/

Comment: needs a document.ready or something. it's running before the dom loads.

Comment: What do you mean you want to "call" it?

Comment: You start your loop at 0 and there is no element with that ID. You're also executing your code too early in the fiddle.

Comment: also, technically an ID that begins with a number is invalid HTML

Comment: @Nikki9696: If you look at the fiddle, it's running in the onLoad. Of course, that may be completely by accident since it's the default for JS Fiddle. The problem is with the index.

Comment: @MattBurland yes, I see that now, and the ids shouldn't just be a number maybe as was mentioned by joe but I'm not positive on that one

Comment: @JoeL: That it absolutely not true.

Comment: Reopened the question, the problem was not that the script was running before the HTML was loaded.

Comment: @JuanMendes: True, but it should probably be closed as a typo anyway.

Comment: @JosephMarikle That's not true in HTML 5, https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute `There are no other restrictions on what form an ID can take; in particular, IDs can consist of just digits, start with a digit, start with an underscore, consist of just punctuation, etc.`

Comment: @JosephMarikle - It's valid in HTML5, although CSS selectors can have a hard time with it.

Comment: @JuanMendes and j08691 Cool! Thanks for letting me know.  The numeric first character restriction on IDs was super annoying.

Comment: @MattBurland So I took at what I wrote and to be honest wondered why I was in that frame of mind. My train of thought was more towards declaring j in `for (var j=0;` In the past, I was always operating this way with loop parameters. But yeah, I feel silly now.

Comment: Related: [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/218196). More importantly, learn how to debug your code. Stack Overflow is not a debugging service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to find an element with the ID of `0` and it doesn't exist so your script errors out when trying to access the `innerHTML` property of null (what was returned by the call to `document.getElementById(0)`). [Dev tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) is your friend, always look for error messages.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

```js
for (j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
  var product = j;
  document.getElementById(product).innerHTML = "blah";
}
```

```html
<span id="1"></span>
<span id="2"></span>
<span id="3"></span>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cq47eo1c/